# Invalid maximum heap size when calling Java from R

Tags: java, r, windows, jvm

I have a R function that starts a Java VM using the `system` function. For example:

```r
system('java -Xmx2000M -jar "C:/myjar.jar"')
```

This has worked for ages, but I now have a problem on some computers where I get the error.

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx2000M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

But this error only occurs when calling Java from within R, if I use the exact same command in the command line it runs without any problem.

The issue occurs with any mayimum heap size above -Xmx1111M

So far I have only observed this error using the latest version of Java `1.8.0_271-b09` previosly I had been uisng `1.8.0_251-b08` without any problems.

In both cases I'm using the 64 Bit version of Java with plently of spare RAM so I'm sure it is not a simple case of running out of memory.

Why can't I sucesfully start Java from R? Has their been some change to the latest version of Java that limits the heap size you can call?

Comment: All the symptoms suggest that you are trying to launch a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: It is definitly 64 Bit and even if it was 32 bit why can I not use more than 1.1 GB

Comment: You are using a JVM that requires contiguous memory for the heap space, but there are native libraries requiring memory below the 2G threshold. Though, 1.1G is low by today’s standards, usually something around 1.4G is possible. Perhaps, being launched by R implies having additional libraries in the user space. However, the error message is quite clear and the limit still in the typical range, so be careful with terms like “definitely” and rather try `system('java -version')`. It doesn’t hurt.

Comment: Fair point, but I get `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)`

Comment: And when you use `java -Xmx2000M -version`?

Comment: The same result

Comment: So it did not fail? Then it’s not the same `java` that produced the error shown in the question.

Comment: No I meant that both `system('java -version')` and `system(java -Xmx2000M -version)` return `64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)` it is still failing

Comment: Ah I have found that system('java -d64 -Xmx2000M -jar "C:/myjar.jar"') works, so something must be switching to 32bit even with the 64bit version as default

Comment: Didn’t know that `-64` has an effect under Windows (or was tagging with `window` rather than `windows` intentional?)

Comment: yes I'm on Windows, perhaps this is the change between v251 and v271 that caused the problem